# Remove hash tag values from url based on link clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm using the script below to add to the url the href of the clicked link. So mysite.com becomes, mysite.com#a1, what I still need to achieve is that if I click on that link again it will remove #a1, so mysite.com#a1, would go back to mysite.com, or mysite.com#a1#a2 becomes mysite.com#a2.

```
//creates href for each of my links
$('.contentTrigger a').attr('href', function(i, value) {
    return "#a" + (i+1);
});

//adds href value to url
$('.contentTrigger a').click(function(event) {
    var currentHash = window.location.hash;
    window.location.hash = currentHash + this.hash;
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about this solution that you are looking for but you can check this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.contentTrigger').toggle(function(){
            $(this).attr({'href':$(this).attr('href')+'#a1'});
            return false;
        },function(){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            var hash = href.lastIndexOf('#');
            var url = href.substring(0,hash);
            $(this).attr({'href':url});
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<a class="contentTrigger" href="http://www.google.com">Click 1</a><br/>
<a class="contentTrigger" href="http://www.google.com#a2">Click 2</a>
```

see the window status bar when you click on each link.